# How to update an existing item ViewModel in an ObservableCollection which is populated by an Observable

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive

Having an ObservableCollection that populates by an observable, I would like to know what is the most effective and right way to update an item ViewModel in the collection if already exists. I came up with 2 solutions:

**Solution 1**

Make the MainViewModel responsible to identify if the item already exists in the ObservableCollection, if yes perform an update:

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
private readonly SortedObservableCollection<IConversationPreviewViewModel> _conversationPreviews = new SortedObservableCollection<IConversationPreviewViewModel>();

public void SubscribeOnConversations()
{
    _observeConversationsUseCase
        .Conversations
        .ObserveOn(_schedulerProvider.Dispatcher)
        .Subscribe(OnNext);
}

private void OnNext(Conversation conversation)
{
    var previewViewModel = _conversationPreviews.FirstOrDefault(it => it.ConversationId == conversation.ConversationId);
    if (previewViewModel == null)
    {
        IConversationPreviewViewModel conversationPreview = _conversationPreviewFactory.Create(conversation);
        _conversationPreviews.Add(conversationPreview);
    }
    else
    {
        previewViewModel.UpdateConversation(conversation);
    }
}
```

**Solution 2**

The main view model is only responsible to add new items but the updating is the responsibility of each item view model itself, subscribing each one to the observable:

```
   public class Conversation
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

public class ConversationItemViewModel
        {
            private int Id { get; set; }

            public string Text { get; private set; }

            public ConversationItemViewModel(Conversation conversation, ObserveConversations observeConversations)
            {
                Id = conversation.Id;
                Text = conversation.Name;

                PrintStatus("ctor");

                observeConversations.Conversations.Where(it => it.Id == Id).Subscribe(OnNext);
            }

            private void OnNext(Conversation conversation)
            {
                Text = conversation.Name;

                PrintStatus("OnNext");
            }

            private void PrintStatus(string from)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Id:{Id} Text:{Text} From: {from}");
            }
        }

   public class ObserveConversations
        {
            public IConnectableObservable<Conversation> Conversations { get; }

            public ObserveConversations()
            {
                Conversations = ConversationsArriving();

                Conversations.Connect();
            }

            public IConnectableObservable<Conversation> ConversationsArriving()
            {
                var list = new List<Conversation>() { new Conversation(){Id = 1, Name = "name1"},
                    new Conversation() {Id = 2, Name = "name2" },
                    new Conversation() {Id = 3, Name = "name3"},
                    new Conversation() {Id = 2, Name = "updatedname2"}, // Update this
                    new Conversation() {Id = 4, Name = "name4"},
                    new Conversation() {Id = 3, Name = "updatedname3"}, // Update this
                };

                return list.ToObservable().Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Publish();
            }
        }

        public class MainViewModel
        {
            private readonly ObserveConversations _observeConversations;

            public MainViewModel(ObserveConversations observeConversations)
            {
                _observeConversations = observeConversations;
            }

            private ObservableCollection<ConversationItemViewModel> ConversationItemViewModels { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ConversationItemViewModel>();

            public void Start()
            {
                _observeConversations.Conversations
                    .Distinct(it => it.Id)
                    .Subscribe(OnNext);
            }

            private void OnNext(Conversation conversation)
            {
                ConversationItemViewModels.Add(new ConversationItemViewModel(conversation, _observeConversations));
            }
        }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var observeConversations = new ObserveConversations();
        var mainViewModel = new MainViewModel(observeConversations);
        mainViewModel.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Personally, I find the solution 2 better since it delegates the responsibility of update to each `ViewModel` each self.

1. Is there a more fine-grained solution than those?
2. Could the creation of multiple subscriptions for each item `ViewModel` in solution 2 create performance issues?

Comment: The creation of two subscriptions will create two complete observable pipelines - which could mean a doubling of you original resource/query - whatever that is doing.

Comment: Not if the observable is hot. So it will deliver only fresh conversations.

Comment: No, I stand by my original comment. It doesn't matter if it is hot or not. There will always be two observable pipelines. But I did say that **could** mean doubling your original resource/query. A hot query will prevent that doubling of your original resource/query - but it doesn't stop two complete observable pipelines being created.

Comment: The thing is that by solution 2 the plan is only not to create just a second subscription (thus a second pipeline) but for each viewmodel create one (thus many complete pipelines). Could this create performance issues?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] so that I can take a look?

Comment: @Enigmativity I updated the solution 2. Please check!